# How to list users from Google Directory from specific domain user gmail account?

Tags: javascript, google-directory-api

I have an application that uses many scopes of Google's API. Initially it was restricted to only users inside my domain (let's call it `lordshark.com` and it IS working perfectly)... but now I was requested to accept any GMail users and the main problem is:

Consider I am logged with someone@**gmail.com**, I would like to retrieve all users in `lordshark.com` domain in Javascript using:

```
gapi.client.directory.users.list({
    'viewType': 'domain_public',
    'customer': 'my_customer',
    'maxResults': 100,
    'orderBy': 'email',
    'domain': 'lordshark.com'
})
```

I already authorized my API Client (https://admin.google.com/lordshark.com/AdminHome?chromeless=1#OGX:ManageOauthClients), already enabled contact sharing (https://admin.google.com/lordshark.com/AdminHome?chromeless=1#AppDetails:service=Directory&flyout=sharing) but still got this response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
                "reason": "forbidden"
            }
        ],
        "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to see what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The user (not only the client ID) has to be authorized to view users in your domain.  Usually this is controlled with admin roles inside the domain.  This means you have to log in as a lordshark.com user to list the users.  The only way around this would be to create a service account as described here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

But that won't work with Javascript so your app would need a back end.